# shorter way to select rows from json array

Tags: php, mysql, json

json column named `linked` is like this:

["378", "377", "356"]

I have some `id` from `ajax` and need to find the corresponding `json` value

and then

select `id` and `title` from rows with `id` as the json elements

```
$st = $db->prepare("select linked from posts where id = " . $_POST['id'] . " limit 1");

$st->execute();

$str = $st->fetchColumn();

$arr = json_decode($str);
$str = implode(",", $arr);

$sql = "select id, title from posts where id in (" . $str . ") order by date desc";

$st = $db->prepare($sql);

$st->execute();

while ($row = $st->fetch()){
    echo ...
}
```

It works, but I suppose - there is a shorter way.

Any suggestion?

Comment: You should normalize your database, store the `linked` items in a separate table linking them to this table. And you should not inject variables in your query, use placeholders and bind the variables instead.

Comment: @jeroen, I'm afraid the new table will have just `id` and again `json` column with linked `ids` array. Or you mean separate column for each `json` element?

Comment: No, a new row for each element.

Comment: The correct place for this question is [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).